# Overwrite specific guice binding through interceptor or listener or preprocessor

Tags: java, dependency-injection, binding, mocking, guice

I was wondering if there is a way in Guice to override a binding through the use of listeners or interceptors before it gets created.

My scenario is:

I have a Module A that binds a client, for example:

```
public static class ProdModule extends AbstractModule {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(Client.class).toInstance(ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build());
        }
    }
```

This binding needs to be mocked. So I would like for the test to add a new Module that registers a Listener (or something) so that when Guice attempts to resolve that binding, I can replace it with whatever binding I want.

I do know about `Modules.override(...)` however this can't be used with my setup. The Code instantiating the Injector is buried in a dependency essentially. I have no access to change the code to use module overwrites, however I can add as many new modules as I want.

I don't want to replace the entire Module nor do I want to change the Module code at all.

I have been trying a few things that either don't work, or I am not sure how to use them:

I tried using `ProvisionListener`. This worked "somewhat". I could overwrite a specific provider by using reflection and changing the result field on the Provision. This did not work for instance bindings.

I tried using the `ElementVisitor` and `BindingTargetVisitor`, however they didn't really do anything for me. I may not understand exactly what the purpose of these two visitors is and I haven't found too much documentation or examples on it.

Comment: From how you've described your restrictions, there's no way to do this.

Comment: @TavianBarnes thank you. I was afraid that is the case. I am currently trying to work around my restrictions in order to use Modules#override

Comment: "*I don't want to replace the entire Module neither do I want to change the Module code at all.*" - why not? Is it not your code? Or are you just trying to avoid refactoring your modules?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're going about this problem backwards - dependency injection exists to *enable* testing, so if you're struggling to write testable code while using a DI framework it's worth stepping back and figuring out what's wrong at a higher level, rather than trying to wrestle the framework into behaving the way you think it should.

"*This binding needs to be mocked.*" is a big red flag. You should almost never need to bind mocks objects, because mocks are brittle and generally meant to be used in single-purpose unit tests, not provided by a DI framework across an application.

If you're writing a unit test, you shouldn't need a framework at all - simply instantiate the class under test *directly*, passing in the necessary mocks. Thanks to dependency injection you should be able to quickly unit test a class in isolation if all its dependencies are mocked out - no framework needed.

If you're writing an integration or other larger test, and therefore need to construct an injector and test the system as a whole, you should ideally have fake (not mock) implementations of the components that cannot be safely tested, and alternate modules to install for such tests. For example your test injector would install `FakeCreditCardProcessorModule` instead of `CreditCardProcessorModule`, and the modules providing the bindings you're trying to test are loosely coupled enough to not care which processor module is installed. If that isn't an option due to overly-coupled modules `Modules.override()` can be used to fake individual bindings.

Only if you're testing a module's logic itself should you want to bind mocks (though generally putting complex logic meriting testing in your modules is discouraged). You should install *just* the module under test, alongside a separate module that binds mocks for any required bindings. This is the only time mocks really make sense with a DI framework.

If none of the above scenarios apply please provide more detail about *what* you're trying to test.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I believe it was an integration test.I agree with all you said. One of my issues was that I did not want to create fake modules (e.g. if something in the actual prod module changes, the fake module would miss that). So i wanted to leave the application alone but specifically replace just the one class (client in this case). Thought of a fake client, but that is not as easy as replacing a java bean, so i thought mocking it would save me some headaches.

Comment: If something in the prod module changes, your tests of that module should start failing (e.g. due to a missing binding), so that should generally be fine. Ideally your modules each represent clearly-decoupled components (e.g. a database module) that provide specific bindings, which makes it easy to introduce fake modules that provide the same bindings. If that doesn't seem feasible it's possible your module(s) are too complex, and you'd benefit from splitting them into smaller, more logically distinct components.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. first, split the module into smaller more specific ones, and for the specific bindings i wanted to override, introduce methods that return the instance and can be overwritten. That way my fake module could extend my prod module and then simply replace the specific value I needed

Comment: Fakes and mocks certainly each have their own tradeoffs, but if your test is complex enough to need a real injector, its unlikely a mock will suffice (for example the same mock may wind up being injected more than once to different call sites). If the logic you're testing is simple enough that mocks suffice you'd probably be better off just constructing the object under test yourself and passing in the mocks directly. If neither case applies I'd revisit your tests (as they're too tightly-coupled to the module's behavior), or your modules themselves (as they have too much internal behavior).